# Can one obtain a path that has the shape of a path with its path effects?

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

I have created a path, say a square. I have then applied paths effects, e.g. lattice deformation, which has turned my square into a rhombus.

If I now select the "Edit path by node" tool, I see that the nodes are still those of the square, plus those of the lattice. This is also the case for a duplicate or a copy of that shape.

[image]

I would like to obtain a path which has the shape I have obtained through path effects, but whose nodes and Bezier handles are the data that governs that shape, i.e. the current shape is directly controlled by them.

[image]

Is that possible ?

I'm using Inkscape 1.0.2.

Comment: Do *Path > Object to Path*. Note that this is destructive, so if you want to keep the object with a path effect, make a duplicate before doing this.

Comment: Thanks Billy, this is exactly what I wanted -- I'm not sure now why I didn't try it in the first place.